# alignment of two different column based on a set of data given

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, alignment

Please help me on how to generate a automatic formula to align this data in excel.

This should be the alignment, data and result:

[image]

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vlookup:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE),"")`

Where $A$2:$B$4 is the array of Data you want to use
False to have the exact value
2 is the second column in Data
IFERROR to remove any unwanted result (if not found, error...)

[image]